# Keras: badalloc with custom generator

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am using keras with a tensorflow-gpu back end on a Ubuntu 17.04 VM.
I have created a custom generator to read inputs and classes from pickle files, but it seems to get the following error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ba
>   d_alloc'
>     what():  std::bad_alloc

the code for loading data can be seen here:

```
    def data_gen(self, pklPaths, batch_size=16):
        while True:
            data = []
            labels = []
            for i, pklPath in enumerate(pklPaths):
                # print(pklPath)
                image = pickle.load(open(pklPath, 'rb'))
                for i in range(batch_size):
                    # Set a label
                    data.append(image[0][0])
                    labels.append(image[1][1])
                yield np.array(data), np.array(labels)
```

then in the train section i'm using a fit generator:

```
vm_model.fit_generator(vm.data_gen(pkl_train), validation_data=vm.data_gen(pkl_validate), epochs=15, verbose=2,
                       steps_per_epoch=(5000/16), validation_steps=(1000/16), callbacks=[tb])
```

the generator should have better memory management than loading everything, however it doesn't seem to be the case! any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean `image[i][0]` and `image[i][1]`? Did you notice that your `i` is reapeated for enumerating pickles and batch_size?

Comment: Image is set by loading a pkl file so it would not be [i] 
You do have a point on the loops, but it is a pasting error
I think I figured it out, will post an answer as soon as I confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so i found the issue so I'm answering my own question.
Basically, previous one had one unnecessary loop and also kept increasing the size of data and labels essentially loading the entire data in memory:

```
    def data_gen(self, pklPaths, batch_size=16):
    while True:
        data = []
        labels = []
        for i, pklPath in enumerate(pklPaths):
            # load pickle
            image = pickle.load(open(pklPath, 'rb'))
            # append
            data.append(image[0][0])
            labels.append(image[1])
            # if batch is complete yield data and labels and reset
            if i % batch_size == 0 and i != 0:
                yield np.array(data), np.array(labels)
                data.clear()
                labels.clear()
```